# Why we can set Lorentz generators to be antisymmeric?

Tags: special-relativity, operators, angular-momentum, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am following Weinberg 2.4 and I understand why $\omega_{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric, but he says after expanding $$U(1 + \omega, \epsilon) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}i\omega_{\rho \sigma}J^{\rho \sigma} - i\epsilon_{\rho}P^{\rho} + ...\tag{2.4.3}$$

> Since $\omega_{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric. we can take it's coefficient $J^{\rho \sigma}$ to be sntisymmetric also
> $$J^{\rho \sigma} = - J^{\sigma \rho}\tag{2.4.5}$$

I can't understand how and why $J$ must be antisymmetric. Is there any physical relation we can use to set it that way?

Comment: Hint: How much would a symmetric piece contribute to eq. (2.4.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every rank 2 tensor can be written in a symmetric and an antisymmetric part. Now note, that the contraction of an antisymmetric and a symmetric tensor is always 0. Thus, decomposing J, the symmetric part vanishes and so only the antisymmetric part contributes.